# Sorting of ArrayList

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have one array list

```
ArrayList itemListWithRank = ItemListDAO.getItemList();
```

and in arraylist `itemListWithRank` there are lots of type of objects values those all are different. And one value from them is item rank that also set with that array list.

Now i want to sort this array list based on accending order of rank. Rank value is already set in this array list.

**How can i sort arraylist which one have lots of type of values....?**

Thanks all....

Comment: Please give an example of the ArrayList content.

Comment: Do those objects in the list have anything in common? Some common interface or base class? How is the rank stored in the list? Can you give us an example?

Comment: Do you use generics? How is your ArrayList declared? What is the Type of the objects in the List?

Comment: arraylist contain price, name, quantity, unit rank of that item , etc.

Comment: as separate elements? In that case you're doing it wrong. You'll want **one** object per item with properties for each of those values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make them all object of a type. either design a common Base class or an `Interface`

and then

use `Comparator` to sort them out

For example.

```
public class SortableFields{
  protected long rank;
  //accessors methods
}
```

assumed that all the objects in arraylist are SortableFields now

Now

```
Collections.sort(list,new Comparator(){
public int compareTo(Object ob1,Object ob){
  return ((SortableFild)ob1.getRank())-((SortableFild)ob2.getRank())
}
});
```

---

Or use reflection hack , *not preferable*

```
Collections.sort(list,new Comparator(){
public int compareTo(Object ob1,Object ob){
     UtilClass.getRank(ob1)-UtilClass.getRank(ob);      
}
});
```

In your UtilClass

```
public int getRank(Object ob){

      Class cl=ob1.getClass();
      Method mthd=cl.getMethod("getRank");
      Integer output=(Integer)mthd1.invoke(ob);
      return output;

}
```

Comment: To be honest for such a basic question, I wouldn't even mention the reflection approach. And **if** you need to post it, then at least extract a `getRank(Object)` method and don't duplicate the code ;-)

Comment: @Joachim It is demonstration not the practical implementation :)

Comment: @Jigar: you'd be surprised how often the "simple demonstration" ends up in production code. It's unfortunate, but unavoidable, it seems. And we all end up having to maintain that code later on.

Comment: @jigar... can i sort  arraylist wihout comparator..? I think without comparator its a junk code ... but it ok ... can i do this without comparator........?

Answer (score 4):

Use `Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)` and pass a custom comparator for your DAO objects.

It's by far easier if all of your list items share a common supertype that provides a method to get the item rank. Assuming you have such an interface, let's call it `RankProvider`, the comparator could look like:

```
public class Comparator<RankProvider> {
  @Override
  public int compare(RankProvider o1, RankProvider o2) {
    return o1.getItemRank().compareTo(o2.getItemRank());
  }
}
```

Pass an instance of this comparator or define an anonymous class.

**Note** - the example give above assumes, that the item rank is either a java primitive (like `int`) or a String or, in other words, is a `Comparable` (directly or after inboxing)

---

If you don't have a common superclass or interface, then comparing is less trivial. You'll either have to *know* all possible types and handle them each by each or you *know* that all types have the same method (name) and you can reflect the rank. One example for a comparator that compares known but random types:

```
public class Comparator {  // no generics this time
  @Override
  public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
     Object[] comparables = new Object{o1, o2};
     int[] ranks = new int[2];

     for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
       if (comparables[i] instanceof MyType1) {
         ranks[i] = ((MyType1) comparables[i]).getRank(); // rank getter for MyType1 type
         continue;
       }

       if (comparables[i] instanceof MyType2) {
         ranks[i] = ((MyType2) comparables[i]).getRank(); // rank getter for MyType2 type
         continue;
       }

       // ...
     }
     return ranks[0] - ranks[1];  // ascending order
  }
}
```

This could be done if you have no chance to refactor your DAOs to implement a shared interface.

Comment: **Note**, there are lots of type of objects values those all are different.

Answer (score 2):

```
Collections.sort(itemListWithRank ,new Comparator<Person>() {

    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
        return Integer.valueOf(o1.id).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2.id));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/wiki/LambdajFeatures), which allows this construct

```
List<Person> sorted = sort(persons, on(Person.class).getAge());
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, every objects in the ArrayList must have some common parent in their hierarchy or implements an interface which define some way to get the rank. For example, all of them must implement this interface :

```
interface Rankable {
    public int getRank();
}
```

The you can create a custom [Comparator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) :

```
Comparator<Rankable> myComparator = new Comparator<Rankable>() {
    public int compare(Rankable o1, Rankable o2) {
        return o1.getRank() - o2.getRank();
    }
    public equals(Object obj) {
        return obj == this;
    }
}
```

And finally sort your ArrayList :

```
Collections.sort(itemListWithRank, myComparator);
```

You can also implements `Comparable` in all your objects in the `ArrayList` and then the legacy sort method, but this will be less flexible if you're planning on doing other kind of comparison on them.