# Sort Java Collection

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have a Java collection:

```
Collection<CustomObject> list = new ArrayList<CustomObject>();
```

`CustomObject` has an `id` field now before display list I want to sort this collection by that `id`.

Is there any way I could that do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a Collection<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477261/how-to-sort-a-collectiont)

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Use a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
List<CustomObject> list = new ArrayList<CustomObject>();
Comparator<CustomObject> comparator = new Comparator<CustomObject>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(CustomObject left, CustomObject right) {
        return left.getId() - right.getId(); // use your logic
    }
};

Collections.sort(list, comparator); // use the comparator as much as u want
System.out.println(list);
```

Additionally, if `CustomObject`implements `Comparable`, then just use `Collections.sort(list)`

### With JDK 8 the syntax is much simpler.

```
List<CustomObject> list = getCustomObjectList();
Collections.sort(list, (left, right) -> left.getId() - right.getId());
System.out.println(list);
```

Much simplier

```
List<CustomObject> list = getCustomObjectList();
list.sort((left, right) -> left.getId() - right.getId());
System.out.println(list);
```

Simplest

```
List<CustomObject> list = getCustomObjectList();
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(CustomObject::getId));
System.out.println(list);
```

Obviously the initial code can be used for JDK 8 too.

Comment: What if they want to sort more than one time?

Comment: Edited the answer, please check. Obviously its not a big deal if it is understandable how to use the comparator. If you can do it one time, it can be done n times also :)

Comment: Aye ... if class implement comparable then dont need to pass comparator ...nice ..ta

Comment: Who gave the down vote, can you enlighten me? please? May be I can learn something better.

Comment: The method sort(List<T>, Comparator<? super T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (Collection, Comparator)  you cannot pass a Collection to sort method which is dead annoying

Comment: The sort method works for Lists, not Collections.  The type of the list variable should be changed to List for this example to work.

Comment: Comparison by subtraction should be avoided, please see [Java Integer compareTo() - why use comparison vs. subtraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728793/java-integer-compareto-why-use-comparison-vs-subtraction)

Answer (score 36):

The question is: "Sort Collection". So you can't use `Collections.sort(List<T> l, Comparator<? super T> comparator)`.

Some tips:

**For Collection type:**

```
Comparator<String> defaultComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
   @Override
   public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
       return o1.compareTo(o2);
   }
};

Collection<String> collection = getSomeStringCollection();
String[] strings = collection.toArray(new String[collection.size()]);
Arrays.sort(strings, defaultComparator);
List<String> sortedStrings = Arrays.asList(strings);

Collection<String> collection = getSomeStringCollection();
List<String> list = new ArrayList(collection);
Collections.sort(list, defaultComparator);
collection = list; // if you wish
```

**For List type:**

```
List<String> list = getSomeStringList();
Collections.sort(list, defaultComparator);
```

**For Set type:**

```
Set<String> set = getSomeStringSet();
// Than steps like in 'For Collection type' section or use java.util.TreeSet
// TreeSet sample:
// Sorted using java.lang.Comparable.
Set<String> naturalSorted = new TreeSet(set);

Set<String> set = getSomeStringSet();
Set<String> sortedSet = new TreeSet(defaultComparator);
sortedSet.addAll(set);
```

**Java 8 version. There is `java.util.List#sort(Comparator<? super E> c)` method**

```
List<String> list = getSomeStringList();
list.sort(defaultComparator);
```

or

```
List<String> list = getSomeStringList();
list.sort((String o1, String o2) -> o1.compareTo(o2));
```

or for types that implements Comparable:

```
List<String> list = getSomeStringList();
list.sort(String::compareTo);
```

Comment: I asked this question 4 years ago and you are answering now.

Comment: Thanks for u reply. Really appreciate it. 4 years and still wrong answer is marked as correct one. Who is the bad guy?

Comment: @Makky becuase it answers for a List, not a collection

Answer (score 12):

A slightly different example say if you have a class that doesn't implement Comparable but you still want to sort it on a field or method.

```
Collections.sort(allMatching, new Comparator<ClassOne>() {
  @Override public int compare(final ClassOne o1, final ClassOne o2) {
    if (o1.getMethodToSort() > o2.getMethodToSort()) {
      return 1;
    } else if (o1.getMethodToSort() < o2.getMethodToSort()) {
      return -1;
    }  
    return 0;
  }
});
```

Comment: The if statement you implemented does exactly what `compareTo()` does already.

Comment: The difference is that in this example the class ClassOne is not a comparable class, it doesn't implement Comparable. I was just trying to show an example of how you can use a collection and a comparator to sort non comparable objects. ClassOne has no compareTo method..

Comment: doesnt work with java 6 (Collections.sort limited to List)

Comment: You won't find a Collections.sort taking a Set in Java 7 or 8. By definition a List is an ordered sequence of elements whereas Set is a distinct list of elements which is unordered. If you want ordering in a Set look at TreeSet

Answer (score 8):

You should implement the `Comparator` interface.

example:

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<CustomObject> 
{
    @Override
    public int compare(CustomObject o1, CustomObject o2) {
        return o1.getId().compareTo(o2.getId());
    }
}
```

Then you can use the Collections classes `Collections.sort()` method:

```
Collections.sort(list, new CustomComparator());
```

Answer (score 5):

Implement the [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface on your customObject.

Answer (score 5):

As of Java 8 you now can do it with a stream using a lambda:

```
list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(customObject::getId))
             .foreach(object -> System.out.println(object));
```

Answer (score 5):

A lot of correct answers, but I haven't found this one:
Collections cannot be sorted, you can only iterate through them.

Now you can iterate over them and create a new sorted `something`. Follow the answers here for that.

Answer (score 4):

[`Comparator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) is the way

**Also See**

- [sorting-of-arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309136/sorting-of-arraylist/5309169#5309169)

Answer (score 2):

Use [sort](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29).

You just have to do this:

> All elements in the list must implement the Comparable interface.

(Or use the version below it, as others already said.)

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8 you have several options, combining method references and the built-in `comparing` comparator:

```
import static java.util.Comparator.comparing;

Collection<CustomObject> list = new ArrayList<CustomObject>();

Collections.sort(list, comparing(CustomObject::getId));
//or
list.sort(comparing(CustomObject::getId));
```

Answer (score 0):

[SortedSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) and Comparator. Comparator should honour the *id* field.

Comment: @Qwerky - I know he has a list. I am suggesting him to use a Set. Unless he wants to maintain duplicates and insertion order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java Custom Class for the purpose of sorting.

Answer (score 0):

Your example:

```
Collection<CustomObject> list = new ArrayList<CustomObject>();
```

You can also use a comparator:

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparingLong(CustomObject::getSomethingToCompare));
```

Just replace the comparingLong method, there are quite a few options, but it depends on what you want to pass on the "getSomethingToCompare".

This [link](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-comparator-comparing) may help too.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use:

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<CustomObject>() {
    public int compare(CustomObject obj1, CustomObject obj2) {
        return obj1.id - obj2.id;
    }
});
System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score -3):

To be super clear, Collection.sort(list, compartor) does not return anything so something like this `list = Collection.sort(list, compartor);` will throw an error (void cannot be converted to [list type]) and should instead be `Collection.sort(list, compartor)`

Comment: Totall irrelevant answer.