# Using Collections.sort() method to sort objects alphabetically

Tags: java

I've tried to use `Collections.sort(shapes)` but it's giving me this error:

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List<T>) of type Collections is not applicable for the 
 arguments (ArrayList<CreateShape>). The inferred type CreateShape is not a valid substitute for the 
 bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

How should I fix that?

CreateSpace class

```
 public class CreateSpace implements Space{

            private int height;
        private int width;
        private String layout;
        private char[][] space;
        private Shape originalShape;
        private ArrayList<CreateShape> shapes = new ArrayList<CreateShape>();

        public CreateSpace(int height, int width, char[][] space, String layout)
        {
            this.height = height;
            this.width = width;
            this.space = space;
            this.layout = layout;
        }
    public void placeShapeAt(int row, int col, Shape shape)
        {

            int sHeight = shape.getHeight();
            int sWidth = shape.getWidth();
            if(shape.getHeight() + row > space.length || shape.getWidth() + col > space[0].length)
                throw new FitItException("Out of bounds!");
            char [][] spaceWithShapes = space;
            if(shapeFitsAt(row, col, shape) == true)
            {
                for(int r = 0; r < sHeight; r++)
                {
                    for(int c = 0; c < sWidth; c++)
                    {

                        if(spaceWithShapes[r+row][c+col] == '.' && shape.isFilledAt(r, c) == false)
                            spaceWithShapes[r+row][c+col] = (((CreateShape)shape).getShape()[r][c]);
                    }
                //  shapes.add((CreateShape)shape);
                    Collections.sort(shapes); // <<------- getting an error here
                }
                spaceWithShapes = space;
                shapes.add((CreateShape)shape);
Collections.sort(shapes); // <<------- getting an error here
            }
        }
```

Comment: My first impression is that it's due to your CreateShape class not extending Comparable. You need to @Override a compare() method in order for sorting to work.

Comment: Check [this](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/java-arraylist-of-object-sort-example-comparable-and-comparator/). You need to implement comparable and comparator in your Shape class, and then you can use Collections.sort() on your `ArrayList`

Comment: You can extend a Comparator() by overriding compare() method.

Comment: right now you have ```CreateSpace implements Space```, you need to have ```CreateSpace implements Space, Comparable<Space>```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort Java Collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957631/sort-java-collection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the error because when you call `Collections.sort()` passing only a `List<T>` as parameter, it expects that the list elements implement the `Comparable` interface. Since this is not the case for `CreateShape`, `sort()` has no way to know how these objects should be sorted.

Here are two options you should consider:

1. `CreateShape` could implement `Comparable<CreateShape>`: do this if you think `CreateShape` instances have a natural order in which they should be sorted. If you wanted to sort by a `char` field, for example:

   ```
   class CreateShape implements Comparable<CreateShape> {
        private char displayChar;

        public char getDisplayChar() {
            return displayChar; 
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(CreateShape that) {
            return Character.compare(this.displayChar, that.displayChar);
        }
    }
   ```

Then you could simply call `Collections.sort()`:

```
Collections.sort(shapes);
```

2. Create a custom `Comparator<CreateShape>`: do this if you want to sort `CreateShape` instances arbitrarily. You could have a `Comparator` that sorts by name, another that sorts by id, etc. Example:

   ```
   enum DisplayCharComparator implements Comparator<CreateShape> {
       INSTANCE;

       @Override
       public int compare(CreateShape s1, CreateShape s2) {
           return Character.compare(s1.getDisplayChar(), s2.getDisplayChar());
       }
   }
   ```

Then you should call `Collections.sort()` passing the comparator as parameter:

```
Collections.sort(shapes, DisplayCharComparator.INSTANCE);
```

Note I implemented `DisplayCharComparator` as a singleton. That's because it has no state, so there is no need to have more than one instance of this comparator. An alternative is to use a static variable:

```
class CreateShape {

    static final Comparator<CreateShape> DISPLAY_CHAR_COMPARATOR =
        new DisplayCharComparator();

    static class DisplayCharComparator implements Comparator<CreateShape> { ... }

    // rest of the code
}
```

Or, if you're using Java 8, you can use [`Comparator.comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-):

```
shapes.sort(Comparator.comparing(CreateShape::getDisplayChar));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @AndersonVieira! But Im trying to compare `char displayChar` (as I do not have any String value) but getting the error when I do this: `return this.dc.compareTo(other.dc);`

Comment: @John For comparing `chars`s you could do `return Character.compare(c1, c2);`. I updated the answer.