# JTable, get data from another method an sort it?

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable, jframe

Normally i get the Data from my Tablemodel

```
    table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
        new Object[][] {
            {"xxx", new Integer(10)},
            {"xx", new Integer(40)},
            {"x", new Integer(20)},
            {"xxxxxx", new Integer(50)},
            {"xxxxx", new Integer(30)},
        },
        new String[] {
            "name", "tel"
        }
```

But now i would get the Data from the "name" and "tel" from other Methods. The first method returns a String, who i would put in the "name".
The second method returns a Integer, who i would put in the "tel".
Then i would sort it, that the lowest integer is the first. Any name has his own telephonenumber.

My method Sorter:

```
public void sort()
{
     TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>();
        table.setRowSorter( sorter );
        sorter.setModel( model );   
}
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {}
```

But it doesn't sort, i don't know what i should do.

Comment: Unrelated, but: Don't use Integers for telephone numbers!

Comment: I don't know how i get the (dynamic) data from a other method, 
And second problem is that i can't sort my data. 
sorter.setSortable(2, true); <- so i specify the column to sort, but that doesn't works, too :(

Comment: I think you will have to provide more code, then, particularly how you create/populate the table and how you (try to) sort it.

Comment: I don't understand your question. But you only have two columns, so if you want to sort the 2nd column you would use "1" as the index for the sorter.

Answer (score 0):

Check this you should get your answer

[Sort Java Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957631/sort-java-collection)

Sorting is best when you hava made a collection. I preffer to make a collection than sort it and than display it on JTable.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/algorithms/