# Sorting of Authors Cycle ArrayList in JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` of Johnsons' Cycles found by  Using an `API`. Now I have to sort this ArrayList but I was stuck to do so. I am newbie in `JAVA`. I would be very thankful If someone please help me. The `ArrayList` looks like

```
[[Hausi Müller, Johannes Martin, Bruce Winter, J Martin], [Kenny Wong, Johannes Martin], [Kenny Wong, Kostas Kontogiannis, Johannes Martin, Bruce Winter, J Martin], [Ludger Martin, Johannes Martin, Bruce Winter, J Martin], [Arun Venkataramani, Jian Yin, J-P Martin, Michael Dahlin, J Martin], [Kenny Wong, Kostas Kontogiannis, Johannes Martin], [Kostas Kontogiannis, Kenny Wong, Johannes Martin], [Augustin Lux, Christophe Le Gal, James L Crowley], [Christophe Le Gal, Augustin Lux, James L Crowley]]
```

This is a part of the big list.

Comment: `Collections.sort()` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort Java Collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957631/sort-java-collection)

Comment: What are the sorting conditions? What defines the order of the elements?

Comment: It's not `ArrayList`. It is `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`. Isn't it?

Comment: @Rustam It is ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>. and it is in the result of 
 
I have a graph in which vertices are authors and edges are co-authorship relation. Then I call JohnsonSimpleCycles<V,E> jSC = new JohnsonSimpleCycles<>(); jSC.setGraph((DirectedGraph<V, E>) directedGraph); List<?> savedElements = jSC.findSimpleCycles(); System.out.println(cycles); That ArrayList of ArrayList is the output of this function. Now I have to sort these inner list on the bases of their number of authors.

Comment: @NicholasRobinson on the number of authors in the inner list.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use [`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) function. Basically this function take a list as an argument and sort it using a custom `Comparator` or the `Comparable` interface of the elements present in the list.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html) is the documentation to sort collections (so also `ArrayList`) in java.

Here an example of a custom comparator for `List<String>` elements (it can be used if the api returns an object of type `List<List<String>>`.

```
public CustomComparator implements Comparator<List<String>> {
    public int compare(ArrayList<String> o1, ArrayList<String> o2) {
        return o1.size() - o2.size(); 
    }
}

....

List<List<String>> myResult = ....;
Collections.sort(myResult, new CustomComparator());
// Here myResult is sorted by size of inner lists.
```

**Note:** If you like to sort on the other direction simply change compare function to `return o2.size() - o1.size()`

Comment: Collections.sort does not work. As these arraylist of arraylist are the output johnsons cycle detector. and I want to sort these cycles by the number of authors in the list. If an ArrayList has six authors and the other has five then I want to place the second list (having five authors) first and then first list (having six authors).

Comment: You have to write a custom comparator. Collections.sort works without problem. Post the type of the arrayList returned by this library and I will add a custom comparator to show you how to do that.

Comment: Thanks. 
 
I have a graph in which vertices are authors and edges are co-authorship relation. Then I call JohnsonSimpleCycles<V,E> jSC = new JohnsonSimpleCycles<>(); jSC.setGraph((DirectedGraph<V, E>) directedGraph); List<?> savedElements = jSC.findSimpleCycles(); System.out.println(cycles); That ArrayList of ArrayList is the output of this function. Now I have to sort these inner list on the bases of their number of authors.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example how to sort your Objects via `Collections.sort` by using a `comparator`:

```
       //this example is a snippet from my actual project, 
        //but it fits your question very well I think

            Comparator<TMObject> comp = getTmObjectComparator();
            int leastTMC = Collections.min(tmObjectList, comp).getTMC();

            private Comparator<TMObject> getTmObjectComparator() {
                return new Comparator<TMObject>() {


                  @Override
                  public int compare(TMObject o1, TMObject o2) {

                    //I compare if the int TMC of Object one 
                    //is bigger than the int TMC of Object two
                    //this also works with alphabetical order

                    if (o1.getTMC() > o2.getTMC()) {

                      //returning a Number > 0 means it is superordinate
                      return 1;
                    }
                     //returning a Number < 0 means it is subordinate
                    return -1;
                  }
                };
              }
```

If your Object is as Simple as a String you can also compare the strings with  `o1.compareTo(o2)`. Thats quite the basic.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an arraylist of arraylists I suggest you do

```
for(List<String> list: yourListOfLists){
 Collections.sort(list); }
```

Now, every list in your list is sorted, but how do you want to sort the list-of-lists?

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to List<String>

Comment: Hmm... then you have a list of Objects (can you show how you built your list?). Try Collections.sort(yourListOfLists); if it does the trick.

Comment: I have a graph in which vertices are authors and edges are co-authorship relation. Then I call JohnsonSimpleCycles<V,E> jSC = new JohnsonSimpleCycles<>();
     jSC.setGraph((DirectedGraph<V, E>) directedGraph);
     List<?> savedElements = jSC.findSimpleCycles();
     System.out.println(cycles); That ArrayList of ArrayList is the output of this function. Now I have to sort these inner list on the bases of their number of authors.

Comment: You print, System.out.println(cycles); but I can't see what "cycles" is... If you want to sort according to the number of authors, this is an important information that you need to include in your original question.

Comment: Sorry the cycles is actually savedElements.                              savedElements = jSC.findSimpleCycles() this is the output and I have to sort this according to number of authors in each returned cycle of saved elements. I have printed it to see its output. Yes I want to sort according to the number of authors in each ArrayList of ArrayList.

Comment: To help you building the comparator, we need to know exatcly what's in your list. A List of lists of what? Ie. List<?> savedElements you need to define what '?' is.

Comment: In savedElements, the cycles of authors found in the Publication graph made from a list of authors is saved. This  graph has vertices that represents authors and edges are co-authorship relation. Then I call JohnsonSimpleCycles<V,E> jSC = new JohnsonSimpleCycles<>(); jSC.setGraph((DirectedGraph<V, E>) directedGraph); List<?> savedElements = jSC.findSimpleCycles(); System.out.println(cycles); That ArrayList of ArrayList is the output of this function. Now I have to sort these inner list on the bases of their number of authors