# How to Manually Sort ArrayList<Model> in Android?

Tags: java, android

I have a Model Class and I am trying to **Sort The ArrayList list according to the ID** in Model Class. How can I get a soretd list in a simple way ?

**My Model Class includes :**

```
ID :      Name :
1         Apple
2         Microsoft
3         Samsung
4         Lenovo
5         Mi
```

Comment: Check out the sorting feature of Java Streams

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort Java Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957631/sort-java-collection). I downvoted because [no apparent research](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) was done.

Comment: @Austin, I am new with Android & java platforms. Also i have less experience with programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort any collection in java by this code:

```
Collections.sort(mList, new Comparator<YourModel>(){
    public int compare(YourModel obj1, YourModel obj2) {
        return Integer.valueOf(obj1.ID).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(obj2.ID));
        // Or you can compare any field of your object
    }
});
```

for more detail go to [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List%3CT%3E,%2520java.util.Comparator%3C?%2520super%2520T%3E))

Comment: thanks. Actually I was ignorant about Collections.sort can be used this way. I was  discovered my own method to sort by Index according to ID.