# How do I sort an ArrayList based on its object's contents

Tags: java, arraylist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting an ArrayList of Contacts based on name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814095/sorting-an-arraylist-of-contacts-based-on-name)
>   [Sorting of ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5309136/sorting-of-arraylist)

I have an `ArrayList` of type `Person` and I want to sort it based on the person's ages: `person.getAge()`.

How can I do that, so that the list of people is ordered by their age?

Comment: Look into `Comparator` interface and `Collections.sort(...)` method

Comment: look this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814095/sorting-an-arraylist-of-contacts-based-on-name?lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ArrayList<Person> people = . . .;
Collections.sort(people, new Comparator<Person>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
            final int age1 = o1.getAge();
            final int age2 = o2.getAge();
            return age1 < age2 ? -1 : age1 > age2 ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }
);
```

In Java 7, you can use `return Integer.compare(age1, age2);` instead.

Alternatively, you can have `Person` implement `Comparable<Person>`. However, then you could only sort on the one attribute.

Comment: Did you mean the static `Integer.compare(int, int)`?

Comment: @PaulBellora - Yes, thanks. I'll fix the typo.

Comment: The last approach still works in Java 8. Most of the number classes have a compare method, I assume Boolean has the same as well (not checked)

Comment: @LunarWatcher - Yes, `Boolean` implements `Comparable<Boolean>`. It treats `true` as greater than `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the comment, something along these lines:

```
Collections.sort(personList, new Comparator<Person>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
        return new Integer(p1.getAge()).compareTo(p2.getAge());
    }
});
```

---

**Relevant documentation**

- [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)
- [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Answer (score 0):

Define your `comparator`, which compares using the `age` attribute Only. Use the same in collection sort method [**sort(java.util.List, java.util.Comparator)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List, java.util.Comparator)) which accepts the comparator.

```
        Collections.sort(peopleList, new Comparator<Person>(){
             @Override
             public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
                return Integer.valueOf(p1.getAge()).compareTo(p2.getAge());
             }
         });
```

Or **better do below for optimization** as `Integer.compareTo` internally uses `Integer.compare` method.

```
       Collections.sort(peopleList, new Comparator<Person>(){
             @Override
             public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
                return Integer.compare(p1.getAge(), p2.getAge());
             }
         });
```

Comment: This generates a lot of garbage because it creates two `Integer` objects for each comparison. Much better to stick to primitive `int` comparisons.

Comment: @TedHopp Updated the answer with optimized version as well.

Comment: @user521180 You can better use `Integer.compare` method which does the comparison of tow int values for you. I would advice not to implement a  custom comparison.

Answer (score 0):

```
//We can do using TreeMap
//i.e
TreeMap treemap=new TreeMap<int,Person>
//trace over person
for(Person p:YourPersonArrayList)
{
treemap.put(p.getAge(),p);
}
//Finally you get TreeMap which is 
//sorted on Persons age...
```

Comment: Code may not work because i am not sure about int key's in TreeMap<int,Person>,you can use TreeMap Collection to solve your problem